# How to call WMI using MinGW

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, wmi, mingw

After days of searching the web (Including MSDN) for a way to get Hardware unique IDs using C++, I found that I need to use WMI. Actually I could find some good examples as well like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) one. The problem is: I cannot compile it using MinGW however it rund pretty well on Visual Studio using Microsoft compiler, but with MinGW (which my application is compiled with) it gives me dozens of errors.
This could sound an old question but unfortunately I couldn't find a solution so far after days of searching the web. I am using MinGW on Windows 7.

Comment: what kind of information are you talking about ? The C Win32 API provides a lot of functions to get informations from the system.

Comment: You ought to have figured out by yourself that you need to use WMI.  No particular reason that won't work with MinGW, it is just COM calls.  What's the real problem here?

Comment: @SirDarius Information such as Processor ID, Motherboard Serial number, MAC Address.

Comment: @HansPassant You are right I know that I need to use WMI. Can you please give me an example with source code with guidance if there is any specific configuration with the compiler. Thanks

Comment: C++ examples are easy to find in the WMI documentation.  No special compiler config is needed.  Have you even tried this?

Comment: Actually yes, I have tried examples from the WMI documentation and IT IS NOT WORKING with MinGW, I don't know why or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MinGW should allow you to access the Win32 api's without needing Visual Studio.

The following should compile and run with MinGW.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   SYSTEM_INFO siSysInfo;

   // Copy the hardware information to the SYSTEM_INFO structure. 

   GetSystemInfo(&siSysInfo); 

   // Display the contents of the SYSTEM_INFO structure. 

   printf("Hardware information: \n");  
   printf("  OEM ID: %u\n", siSysInfo.dwOemId);
   printf("  Number of processors: %u\n", 
      siSysInfo.dwNumberOfProcessors); 
   printf("  Page size: %u\n", siSysInfo.dwPageSize); 
   printf("  Processor type: %u\n", siSysInfo.dwProcessorType); 
   printf("  Minimum application address: %lx\n", 
      siSysInfo.lpMinimumApplicationAddress); 
   printf("  Maximum application address: %lx\n", 
      siSysInfo.lpMaximumApplicationAddress); 
   printf("  Active processor mask: %u\n", 
      siSysInfo.dwActiveProcessorMask); 

   return 0;
}
```

[Additional reading to help you get started.](http://osix.net/modules/article/?id=670)

Answer (score 4):

MinGW has no support for WMI. There are some efforts in MinGW64 but it still can't be called complete (for example, wbemuuid.lib is missed).

Some projects solve this problem by extending MinGW with missed WMI libraries from Microsoft WMI SDK or MinGW64 (see [this project](http://www.ultimatepp.org/srcimp%24SysInfo%24SysInfo%24en-us.html) or [this thread](http://www.wreckedgames.com/forum/index.php?topic=2584.0) for examples).

Another solution for getting device UIDs for your concrete task may be using of Windows Setup API that is well supported by MinGW. A great example of using it may be found [on CodeProject site](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14412/Enumerating-windows-device).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Microsoft Reference

[Win API System Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)