# How to identify PC (motherboard) in win32 api?

Tags: windows, winapi, uniqueidentifier, identification

Say I have client application that shall identify itself on diferent PCs (say with diferent motherboards) in a unique manner. It shall work on XP sp3 and up. How to get such identifier with win api?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx  Bad idea btw.

Comment: @HansPassant: Why bad idea? Say for example it is a files loader application which reports for base server to gather stats on how many PCs downloaded application?

Comment: @HansPassant: thank you for link! I found quite good code sample here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9997208/1973207